# set radiobutton checked in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How can i set checked state of a radio button in windows phone 8 . I tried and getting error in the line checked .

My code is given below .

```
  if (gender == "f")
            femaleRegRadio.Checked = true;
```

![1](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4He-3mC860FQ2RESXJoSjZpMnc/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Checked` is an event occurs when `CheckBox` is checked. Use `IsChecked` property to set check state